# How to solve Pytest error after iPython installation?

Tags: pytest, ipython, python-3.10, ubuntu-22.04

I try to install ipython [in virtual environment](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/venv.html) on Ubuntu 22.04

```
(virtual_environment) a@zalman:~$ pip3 install ipython
```

After instalation run pytest:

```
(virtual_environment) a@zalman:~$ pytest
============================= test session starts ==============================
platform linux -- Python 3.10.6, pytest-7.0.1, pluggy-1.2.0
rootdir: /home/a
plugins: asyncio-0.21.0
asyncio: mode=strict
collected 1282 items / 1 error / 1281 selected                                 

==================================== ERRORS ====================================
_ ERROR collecting go/pkg/mod/github.com/gopacket/gopacket@v0.0.0-20220819214934-ee81b8c880da/layers/test_creator.py _
.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/_pytest/python.py:599: in _importtestmodule
    mod = import_path(self.path, mode=importmode, root=self.config.rootpath)
.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/_pytest/pathlib.py:533: in import_path
    importlib.import_module(module_name)
/usr/lib/python3.10/importlib/__init__.py:126: in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
<frozen importlib._bootstrap>:1050: in _gcd_import
    ???
<frozen importlib._bootstrap>:1027: in _find_and_load
    ???
<frozen importlib._bootstrap>:1006: in _find_and_load_unlocked
    ???
<frozen importlib._bootstrap>:688: in _load_unlocked
    ???
.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/_pytest/assertion/rewrite.py:162: in exec_module
    source_stat, co = _rewrite_test(fn, self.config)
.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/_pytest/assertion/rewrite.py:364: in _rewrite_test
    tree = ast.parse(source, filename=strfn)
/usr/lib/python3.10/ast.py:50: in parse
    return compile(source, filename, mode, flags,
E     File "/home/a/go/pkg/mod/github.com/gopacket/gopacket@v0.0.0-20220819214934-ee81b8c880da/layers/test_creator.py", line 99
E       print '\n'.join(packet.Test(
E       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
E   SyntaxError: Missing parentheses in call to 'print'. Did you mean print(...)?
=============================== warnings summary ===============================
ipython/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py:889
  /home/a/ipython/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py:889: UserWarning: Attempting to work in a virtualenv. If you encounter problems, please install IPython inside the virtualenv.
    warn(

-- Docs: https://docs.pytest.org/en/stable/how-to/capture-warnings.html
=========================== short test summary info ============================
ERROR go/pkg/mod/github.com/gopacket/gopacket@v0.0.0-20220819214934-ee81b8c880da/layers/test_creator.py
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! Interrupted: 1 error during collection !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
========================= 1 warning, 1 error in 8.11s ==========================
```

I have googled the error without succes. What should I do ? The error is similar outside environment.